# Flutter - Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get an api, I can print the api response in the console. However, when I'm receive the respond to my model class, console shows and error like this

> E/flutter ( 9292): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)]
>   Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of
>   'index'

**model.dart**

```
class CategoryDishes {
  final String dishId;
  final String dishName;
  final String dishDescription;

  CategoryDishes(
      {this.dishId,
      this.dishName,
      this.dishDescription,});

  factory CategoryDishes.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CategoryDishes(
        dishId: json['dish_id'],
        dishName: json['dish_name'],
        dishDescription: json['dish_description'],

  }

  static Resource<List<CategoryDishes>> get all {
    return Resource(
        url: Constants.FOOD_API_URL,
        parse: (response) {
          final result = json.decode(response.body.toString());
          print(response);
          Iterable list = result['category_dishes'];
          return list.map((model) => CategoryDishes.fromJson(model)).toList();
        });
  }
}
```

**web_service.dart**

```
class Resource<T> {
  final String url;
  T Function(Response response) parse;

  Resource({this.url, this.parse});
}

class Webservice {
  Future<T> load<T>(Resource<T> resource) async {
    final response = await http.get(resource.url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      debugPrint("----D------>" + response.body);
      return resource.parse(response);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data!');
    }
  }
}
```

The `debugPrint` showing the api in console, but also the above error showing and the api data not showing on my view that I've created.

What I did wrong?

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Can you post your json data format ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API returning JSON Array ! Try like below !

```dart
static Resource<List<CategoryDishes>> get all {
    return Resource(
        url: Constants.FOOD_API_URL,
        parse: (response) {
            final result = json.decode(response.body.toString());
            print(response);
        //added 0 indexex, so it gets 1st element of JSON Arrays
            Iterable list = result[0]['table_menu_list'][0]['category_dishes'];
            return list.map((model) => CategoryDishes.fromJson(model)).toList();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `E/flutter (25339): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.
E/flutter (25339): Receiver: null
E/flutter (25339): Tried calling: map<CategoryDishes>(Closure: (dynamic) => CategoryDishes)
E/flutter (25339): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
E/flutter (25339): #1      CategoryDishes.all.<anonymous closure> (package:test_flutter_api/model/api_model.dart:54:23)` - now this is the error showing, mapping is error

Comment: `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'`- there is an issue when iterating the respond

Comment: Use Map instead of Iterable of list ! Like => Map list= result[0]['table_menu_list'][0]['category_dishes'][0];

Comment: Y I cannot use iteratable list. And the above code u posted is ok, what will be the return for it upvoted();

Comment: As your error saying you are using iterable<dynermic> instead of Internal.......Map<String,dynemic>
And make sure where array value is the output use index

Comment: If you want list then remove the last index 0. As i updated above !

Comment: Thanku Naveen Avidi :). That clue you gave lead me to solve the issue.. However, there's been an another error `Parsing double values from JSON in Flutter and Dart` and I cleared that out.

Comment: how can i fix it in this code? i don't really get it. ```if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    final songTitle = data['now_playing']['song']['title'];
    final songArtist = data['now_playing']['song']['artist'];
    setState(() {
      titleString = '$songTitle';
    });```

Answer (score 1):

When the API returns an array we can't use

```
 result['category_dishes']
```

Instead we use the result directly since it is a list

```
List list= result ;
list.map((i) =>.....
```

I got the same error and this was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error from firebase because I was not putting the field values in quotes. They must be put in quotes to work correct.

```
products.json?auth=token&orderBy=CreatorID <- Error
```

Simply put the field values in quotes

```
products.json?auth=token&orderBy="CreatorID" <- Resolved
```